# Sound eXchange (SoX): What does -w command line option mean?

Tags: sox

I have SoX version 12.18.1.

What does the `-w` mean on a command line like this:

```
sox -w in.wav -r 80000 -A out.wav
```

I have attempted to find the answer using [online help](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), but have not been able to find anything.

[image: Screenshot of sox showing -w in the fopts list]

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a *reverberation* option

```
 reverb [-w|--wet-only] [reverberance (50%) [HF-damping (50%)
              [room-scale (100%) [stereo-depth (100%)
              [pre-delay (0ms) [wet-gain (0dB)]]]]]]
```

The **-w** option can be given to select only the **wet** signal, thus allowing  it to be processed further, independently of the **dry** signal.

Example

```
sox voice.wav -p reverse reverb -w reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/FAQ), the `-w` flag is one of those that changed at version 14.1:

> **3. Why doesn't this SoX command line I found on the internet work?**
>
> A number of potentially confusing options have been replaced with what
>   we hope are less confusing ones; e.g. -b & -w in SoX versions prior to
>   14.1.0 are now -b (or --bits) 8, and -b 16, and -e is now -n.
>
> The ChangeLog contains full details of any backwards-compatibility
>   issues.

So instead of `-w` we should now use `-b 16` according to the above. I tried it when converting an MS WAV file for Asterisk, and Asterisk is able to play the resulting file as a voicemail outgoing announcement. So `-b 16` worked for me. In case it's useful to anyone doing the same, here's the full command that worked:

```
sox unavail.windows.wav  -r 8000 -c 1 -s -b 16 unavail.wav
```

The Changelog link doesn't give much info, but does have some forward links so [here it is](http://sox.cvs.sourceforge.net/sox/sox/ChangeLog?revision=1.184&view=markup)